# Как сделать так чтобы,когда пользователь ничего не нажимал кнопка исчезала

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import time
from tkinter import *
import random



score, max_score = 0, 20
size_x, size_y = 1280, 700



def put():
    global b
    b = Button(root, text='Нажми', activebackground='red', command=click)
    b.place(x=random.randint(10, size_x - 100), y=random.randint(20, size_y - 60))


def click():
    global score
    b.destroy()
    if score <= max_score:
        score += 1
        put()
    else:
        Label(root, text='Поздравляем\n Вы выиграли').place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)




root = Tk()
root.title('Игра')
root.geometry(f'{size_x}x{size_y}')
root.resizable(False, False)
put()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ничего не нажимал - что именно? Это кнопку? Как он ее нажмет, если она исчезнет? Опишите подробно, что именно вы хотите получить.

Comment: я хочу получить кнопку,которая будет исчезать через 3 секунды

Comment: ну получи) запусти таймер в отдельном потоке, куча же способов есть.

Comment: честно говоря, я не знаю как это сделать

Comment: я пытался,но к сожалению не получилось

Comment: def timer():
    tin = 3
    while tin > 1:
        tin -= 1
        b.destroy()
        put()

Comment: через функцию тоже не получилось,я попробовал передать функцию в put(),но выдало:SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated: command